# normal weights acting on separable Hilbert spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

a normal weight is often definied as a sum of normal positive functionals. question:

If we have a normal weight, definied as above, on a von neumann algebra acting on a

separable hibert space can we always replace a sum of normal functional by a countable

sum of normal functionals?